# Codeigniter Many to Many query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, many-to-many

I have three tables: **users**, **categories** and **users_cateogires**.

I need to get **for a specific user** user all the user table and the name of the categories he has. In simple mySql i would do something like this:

```
select u.*, 
(select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from projects as p where p.user_id = u.id_user) as projects, 
(select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from categories as c where c.id_cat in 
(select cat_id from users_categories where user_id = u.id_user)) 
as categories from users as u
```

But I can't find the way to get this result useing codeigniter's Active Record class.

Comment: You want your query using active records. Is it?

Comment: Yes! That's right.

Comment: why did you not go for joins?

Comment: I believe you can achieve your these results using SQL joins.

Comment: Becuase using joins, the query I get gave me repeated data. The user logs in and see on his profile, his projects, his categories, his info. I need to get one sinlge row with all data.

Comment: So does your "I would do something like this..." sql statement in your question give you the desired result? Is that the Actual SQL you would be using????

Comment: Yes, it does, but I would like to learn codeigniter Active Record Class.

Comment: Using your SQL statement how are you selecting the user?  What you have will give you "everyones" results.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SQL Query directly in the Model

Like this

```
$sql = "select u.*, (select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from projects as p where p.user_id = u.id_user) as projects, (select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from categories as c where c.id_cat in (select cat_id from users_categories where user_id = u.id_user)) as categories from users as u";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(name)');
    $this->db->from('projects p');
    $this->db->where('p.user_id', 'u.id_user');
    $first_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('cat_id');
    $this->db->from('users_categories');
    $this->db->where('user_id', 'u.id_user');
    $second_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(name)');
    $this->db->from('categories as c');
    $this->db->where("c.id_cat in ($second_clause) as u", NULL, FALSE);
    $third_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select();


    $this->db->select('u.*,$first_clause,$third_clause');
    $this->db->from('users as u');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row_array();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

Compiled statements are what you're looking for. Now this might be a quick and dirty way of doing it and there probably is a better way but this should get the job done if youre on a deadline.

The query i've sent is not really checked well, Its just to push you in the right direction.